# Ajax on multi check PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

i want use ajax for sent to saveKrs and save to database. i'm use codeigniter, when i click submit button, there's no event. please help me

```
form_checkbox('checkKrs[]',$row->id, FALSE, 'id=checkKrs')


      <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#save_krs').click(function(){
                 var id_student= $('#id_student').val();
                 var id_semester = $('#id_semester').val();
                    var checkKrs = new Array();
                        $("input:checked").each(function() {
                           data['checkKrs[]'].push($(this).val());
                        })

                         var data = {
                                checkKrs:checkKrs,
                                id_semester:id_semester,
                                id_mahasiswa:id_mahasiswa,
                                is_ajax: '1'
                            };

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "saveKrs",
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: data,
                            beforeSend : fnLoadStart,
                            complete : fnLoadStop,
                            success: function(msg) {
                                //$('#form_data').hide();
                                $('#form_data').html(msg);
                                //$('#report').show();
                            }
                        });
                    alert('Pengisian KRS tidak boleh kosong');
                    return false;
            });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make you sure that you have the right controler and if you form match it.

Comment: There is no one other same id on your page ? And do you have a error message ?

Comment: You can put an alert before "var id_student= $('#id_student').val();" to see if something happend.

Comment: Ok, first thing that draws my attention. You use the data array first, and then you define the same array... Second, if you use, Firefox, Safari or Chrome, you can use `console.log()`to check if your saving all the data in your array. Third, you can make a form with the prefilled data and then call your ajax controller to check if the problem is before sending the data or in the php controller that handles the sent data.

Comment: why on console.log() data is not defined.

var checkKrs = new Array();
                        $("input:checked").each(function() {
                           data['checkKrs[]'].push($(this).val());
                        })